# When I click on radio buttons in RecyclerView, I find the other buttons are selected automatically

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, radio-button

I have three radio buttons on RecyclerView. When I click the first button,
I find the first other buttons selected automatically on scroll

```
class Adpter(var context: Context, var arrayList: ArrayList<Date>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<Adpter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    var view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_ay, parent, false)

    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    var arDat = arrayList[position]
    holder.image_Qus.setImageResource(arDat.image_Qus)
    holder.radio1.text = arDat.text1

    holder.radio2.text = arDat.text2

    holder.radio3.text = arDat.text3
//////////
    holder.radio1.setOnClickListener {

        when (position) {

            0 -> holder.radio1.isChecked
            1 -> holder.radio1.isChecked
            2 -> holder.radio1.isChecked
            3 -> holder.radio1.isChecked
            4 -> holder.radio1.isChecked
            5 -> holder.radio1.isChecked
        }
    }
    holder.radio2.setOnClickListener {

        when (position) {

            0 -> holder.radio2.isChecked
            1 -> holder.radio2.isChecked
            2 -> holder.radio2.isChecked
            3 -> holder.radio2.isChecked
            4 -> holder.radio2.isChecked
            5 -> holder.radio2.isChecked
        }
    }
    holder.radio3.setOnClickListener {

        when (position) {

            0 -> holder.radio3.isChecked
            1 -> holder.radio3.isChecked
            2 -> holder.radio3.isChecked
            3 -> holder.radio3.isChecked
            4 -> holder.radio3.isChecked
            5 -> holder.radio3.isChecked
        }
    }
    ///////////
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return arrayList.size
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var image_Qus = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_Qus)
    var radio1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio1) as RadioButton
    var radio2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio2) as RadioButton
    var radio3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio3) as RadioButton
    var btn_go = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_go) as Button
    var radioGroup = itemView.findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.radioGroup)

}

}
```

Comment: You have to save position of button you clicked. Post your list data

Comment: ``ViewHolder``s are just layouts with views (like your ``TextView``s and ``Button``s) that get reused to display list entries. You're meant to set them up for each entry (including the buttons' checked states) in ``onBindViewHolder``

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by increasing the cache size of the recyclerview. Just ensure that the cache size is good enough for your application.

```
recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);//By the number of items
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.